# Wordpress attachment images only shows 2 results

Tags: wordpress

Well this wordpress code below doesn't give me full attachment results. This code gives me 2 results/images only.  I have searched and found out that I need to put in `'numberposts' => -1'` but still this doesn't work. Any help please....

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => "inherit",                                                                                      'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $album_id
    ); 

    $attachments = get_posts($args);                                                if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    $attachment_source = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
    $attachment_caption = get_post_field('post_excerpt', $attachment->ID);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`'post_status' => "inherit"`,  i guess you should be looking for  `'post_status' => "publish"`**